# Slow query time in postgresql when UTC milliseconds is stored as bigint

Tags: performance, postgresql, time, utc

We are migrating from a time series database (ECHO historian) to a open source database basically due to price factor. Our choice was PostgreSQL as there are no open source time series database. What we used to store in the ECHO was just time and value pairs.
Now here is the problem. The table that I created in postgre consists of 2 columns. First is of "bigint" type to store the time in UTC milliseconds(13 digit number) and second is the value whose data type is set to "real" type. I had filled up around 3.6 million rows (Spread across a time range of 30 days) of data and when I query for a small time range (say 1 day) the query takes 4 seconds but for the same time range in ECHO the response time is 150 millisecs!. 
This is a huge difference. Having a bigint for time seems to be the reason for the slowness but not sure. Could you please suggest how the query time can be improved. 
I also read about using the data type "timestamp" and "timestamptz" and looks like we need to store the date and time as regular format and not UTC seconds. Can this help to speed up my query time?

Here is my table definition :

```
            Table "public. MFC2 Flow_LCL "
Column  |  Type  | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target | Description  
----------+--------+-----------+---------+--------------+-------------

 the_time | bigint |           | plain   |              |
 value    | real   |           | plain   |              |

Indexes:
"MFC2 Flow_LCL _time_idx" btree (the_time)

Has OIDs: no
```

Currently i am storing the time in UTC milliseconds (using bigint). The challenge here is there could be duplicate time value pairs.

This is the query i am using (called through a simple API which will pass table name, start and end time)

```
PGresult *res;

int rec_count;
std::string sSQL;

sSQL.append("SELECT * FROM ");
sSQL.append(" \" ");
sSQL.append(table);
sSQL.append(" \" ");
sSQL.append(" WHERE");
sSQL.append(" time >= ");
CString sTime;
sTime.Format("%I64d",startTime);
sSQL.append(sTime);
sSQL.append(" AND time <= ");
CString eTime;
eTime.Format("%I64d",endTime);
sSQL.append(eTime);
sSQL.append(" ORDER BY time ");

res = PQexec(conn, sSQL.c_str());
```

Comment: Is there an index on the time column?

Comment: Does the table have a definition? Does the query have a plan?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto I am just using the default settings. Haven't created any index. I was under an impression that indexes would be useful if we have related tables & may not be helpful in that case.

Comment: @wildplasser, Its a simple table which has 2 columns (time and value). The query is the select command "select * from <table name> where time >= xxxx and time <= yyyy". Since this is still at evaluation for replacment we haven't gone refinining it.

Comment: **BUT DOES IT HAVE A PRIMARY KEY?** does it have additional indexes? Your question (and all its text) is worthless without the real table definition. BTW: `time` is a reserved word. It is a bad idea to use it as a column name.

Comment: @wildplasser, No, it doesn't have a primary key. That was my first plan tomorrow to make the "time" column as primary key. Using "Time" keyword - I will keep that in mind. And sorry I haven't worked much with relational databases. So, please bear with me.

Comment: Please **edit** your question (the link is under the question to the left) and provide proper information as requested.

Comment: @Erwin - Sure. I will provide the table definition and modify the question.

Comment: @wild Did you take your medicines today? :)

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto  Sorry for the shouting. I am getting a bit fed up with these text-only buzzword-enhanced information-deprived questions, sometimes. But to compensate that, I composed a nice POC.

Comment: There is no problem with UTC seconds. It's just an issue of being consistent.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, I have updated the problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your time series database, if it works like a competitor I examined once, stores data in the order of the "time" column automatically in a heap-like structure. Postgres does *not*. As a result, you are doing an O(n) search [n=number of rows in table]: the entire table must be read to look for rows matching your time filter. A Primary Key on the timestamp (which creates a unique index) or, if timestamps are not unique, a regular index will give you binary O(log n) searches for single records and improved performance for all queries retrieving less than about 5% of the table. Postgres will estimate the crossover point between where an index scan or a full table scan is better.

You probably also want to `CLUSTER` ([PG Docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/sql-cluster.html)) the table on that index.

Also, follow the advice above not to use `time` or other SQL reserved words as column names. Even when it is legal, it's asking for trouble.

[This would be better as a comment, but it is too long for that.]

Comment: @ Andrew, thank you very much for clarifying. Your understanding is absolutely right. Time series DB stores in the order of time, so the performance was good. I wanted to try out this on postgresql to see if we can achieve closer match to real time DB.                 " As a result, you are doing an O(n) search" - yes, this is what is happening. So, I wanted to see changing the data type from "bigint" to "timestamp" would make a difference. I will use the primary key and suggestions from @wildpasser and post my results today. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1702807: Changing the column type won't help. Postgres won't implicitly make any index based on type, only either because it is a PK or declared `UNIQUE`. Plus, of course, any indexes you `CREATE` yourself.

Comment: this is what I understood. I can still use bigint to store the UTC milliseconds but make it as a primary key and test it. Additionally, I can create an index and use it.

Comment: If the times are unique and can be used as a primary key, there is no need to define an index. Postgres will do that for you; your own is unnecessary and redundant. But if you can have multiple entries at the same time, it can't be a PK and requires your own `CREATE INDEX`.

Comment: I just verified a dataset from my time series database and found that timestamps are not unique. So postgre won't allow me to make it as primary key. I created a index for one of the table with 3.6 million rows. Calculated the query response time with and without indexing. There wasn't any significant difference. Am i doing something wrong here? I rebooted my computer after creating index but no change. My query to read from database is just select * with time range. And I am requesting data for a day from the table which has data spread across 2 months.

Comment: After creating the index run the `ANALYZE` command. Then report back.

Comment: Here it is  (This is another table with 1.8 million rows) :                                                   analyzing "public. MFC2 Flow_LCL "
INFO:  " Dx/dcvd MFC2 Flow_LCL ": scanned 9730 of 9730 pages, containing 1800000 live rows and 0 dead rows; 30000 rows in sample, 1800000 estimated total rows


Query returned successfully with no result in 141 ms.

Comment: OK, now that it's analyzed, try the searches again. As a benchmark, I just counted 50,000 rows in a 5 million row table in 19 ms. Narrow rows and an SSD, but that's the picture.

Comment: Here are my test results. On 1.8 million rows, first time query took 1.2 secs and the queries after that took like 110 msec (Reduced to 1/10th time of first query). That's great news for me. Also I observed that Postgresql uses buffers to store the result set. As a result, the first query took longer time but after that it was lot quicker. Can we do something about the first query? Something like prefetching for all tables. I will also check if we can get rid of duplicate time stamps and try to make the first column as primary key. As you said, it might not make much difference

Comment: I have marked as right answer for your suggested approach for using either index or primary key for the tables. Thank you. I am running series of tests to improvise this further. Please let me know if you have any further recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really planning for the [year 2038](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)  problem already? Why not just use an int for time as in standard UNIX?

Comment: :) Not exactly. We can't use int because range is +-2147483647 but what we need to store is a 13 digit number like this 1363192230122 (upto millisec precision) (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-numeric.html)

Comment: Then you are storing UTC milliseconds, not UTC seconds.

Comment: Yes Pieter. I should have made that clear in my problem statement. Let me see if it is possible to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET search_path=tmp;

  -- -------------------------------------------
  -- create table and populate it with 10M rows
  -- -------------------------------------------
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;

SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE old_echo
        ( the_time timestamp NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , payload DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL
        );

INSERT INTO old_echo (the_time, payload)
SELECT now() - (gs * interval '1 msec')
        , random()
FROM generate_series(1,10000000) gs
        ;

-- DELETE FROM old_echo WHERE random() < 0.8;

VACUUM ANALYZE old_echo;

SELECT MIN(the_time) AS first
        , MAX(the_time) AS last
        , (MAX(the_time) - MIN(the_time))::interval AS width
FROM old_echo
        ;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM old_echo  oe
JOIN (
        SELECT MIN(the_time) AS first
        , MAX(the_time) AS last
        , (MAX(the_time) - MIN(the_time))::interval AS width
        , ((MAX(the_time) - MIN(the_time))/2)::interval AS half
        FROM old_echo
        ) mima ON 1=1
WHERE oe.the_time >= mima.first + mima.half
AND  oe.the_time < mima.first + mima.half + '1 sec':: interval
        ;
```

RESULT:

```
                                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                                                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.06..59433.67 rows=1111124 width=64) (actual time=0.101..1.307 rows=1000 loops=1)
   ->  Result  (cost=0.06..0.07 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.049..0.050 rows=1 loops=1)
         InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
           ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=1 loops=1)
                 ->  Index Scan using old_echo_pkey on old_echo  (cost=0.00..284873.62 rows=10000115 width=8) (actual time=0.021..0.021 rows=1 loops=1)
                       Index Cond: (the_time IS NOT NULL)
         InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
           ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
                 ->  Index Scan Backward using old_echo_pkey on old_echo  (cost=0.00..284873.62 rows=10000115 width=8) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)
                       Index Cond: (the_time IS NOT NULL)
   ->  Index Scan using old_echo_pkey on old_echo oe  (cost=0.01..34433.30 rows=1111124 width=16) (actual time=0.042..0.764 rows=1000 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((the_time >= (($0) + ((($1 - $0) / 2::double precision)))) AND (the_time < ((($0) + ((($1 - $0) / 2::double precision))) + '00:00:01'::interval)))
 Total runtime: 1.504 ms
(13 rows)
```

UPDATE: since the timestamp appears to be non-unique (btw: what do duplicates *mean* in that case?) I added an extra key column. An ugly hack, but it works here. query time 11ms for 10M -80% rows. (number of rows hit 210/222067):

```
CREATE TABLE old_echo
        ( the_time timestamp NOT NULL
        , the_seq SERIAL NOT NULL -- to catch the duplicate keys
        , payload DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL
        ,       PRIMARY KEY(the_time, the_seq)
        );

    -- Adding the random will cause some timestamps to be non-unique.
    -- (and others to be non-existent)
INSERT INTO old_echo (the_time, payload)
SELECT now() - ((gs+random()*1000::integer) * interval '1 msec')
        , random()
FROM generate_series(1,10000000) gs
        ;

DELETE FROM old_echo WHERE random() < 0.8;
```

Comment: BTW: I reran the same query with 100M rows * 20%, and it completed in 19 ms, yielding 205 rows.

Comment: @wildpasser - Thank you for the test code. The results looks amazing.  I will make the changes as per your suggestions and post my results today.

Comment: @wildpasser - The time is not unique in my case. So, can't use it as primary key.